# process facebook feeds dynamically in adobe flash builder

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, facebook-graph-api, flash-builder

I am trying to process the user feeds retrieved from facebook by dynamically adding them to the flash app, and i need the feed to be displayed in a box with its publisher name and picture beside it (as normal)..

the question is how could i display them aligned under each other if i don't know their heights? is there a way to just add them under each other without specifying the height?
like in html adding divs under each other?

and other question how to add a scroll bar if the content exceeds the flash window?

iam new to as3 & flash so any advice will help.. thanks..

my code:

```
        protected function getFeedsHandler(result:Object,fail:Object):void
        {
            if(result)
            {
                var i:Number;

                for(i=0;i<10;i++)
                    if(result[i])
                    {
                        var fdLbl= new Label();
                        addElementAt(fdLbl,1);

                        fdLbl.text=result[i].message;
                        fdLbl.x=20;
                        fdLbl.y=(i+2)*100;
                        fdLbl.width=400;

                        var fdImg= new Image();
                        addElementAt(fdImg,1);

                        fdImg.source=FacebookDesktop.getImageUrl(result[i].from.id,"small");
                        fdImg.x=20;
                        fdImg.y=(i+2)*80;
                        fdImg.width=400;

                        var nameLbl= new Label();
                        addElementAt(nameLbl,1);

                        nameLbl.text=result[i].from.name;
                        nameLbl.x=20;
                        nameLbl.y=(i+2)*90;


                    }
            }
```

the interface:

```
<s:Button id="loginoutBtn" right="10" top="10" label="Log out"
          click.loggedin="logout(event)"
          label.loggedout="Log in" click.loggedout="login(event)"/>
<s:Form includeIn="loggedin" left="70" top="10">
    <s:FormItem label="User">
        <s:Label id="nameLbl" text=""/>
    </s:FormItem>
    <s:FormItem label="birthday">
        <s:Label id="brthday"/>
    </s:FormItem>
    <s:FormItem label="feeds">
        <s:Image id="feedImg"/>
        <s:Label id="feedLbl" x="0"/>
        <s:Label id="statusLbl" width="405"/>
    </s:FormItem>
</s:Form>
<s:Image id="userImg" includeIn="loggedin" left="10" top="10" width="50"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

So it looks like you're using Flex and specifically you're using the spark components.  In using Spark there's a couple of options on how you would achieve this, one option is to put the component you made above into a VGroup.  The VGroup vertically stacks visual components, it has a property called gap you can set to add or remove spacing between the components (number of pixels between each object nested into the VGroup).  The addition of a s:Scroller component wrapping the VGroup will give you the scroll bars, essentially the way this works is you set the size on the s:Scroller to the size you want to visible (can be a percentage like 100% width/height of the view/container), then you set no explicit size on the VGroup, the VGroup will expand to have a height equal to the height of all the components nested in it plus any padding plus the gap space, the scroller will take care of figuring out how big the scroll tab button should be and adjust the scrollRect on the VGroup for you, essentially it's going to work like magic :).  This would look something like the following:

```
<s:Scroller width="100%" height="100%">
    <s:VGroup id="loadedContentVGroup">
        <yourpackage:YourCustomComponent/>
    </s:VGroup>
</s:Scroller>
```

If you don't constrain the scroller's height and width it will not work as it doesn't have a defined region to draw in and will just become as large as it's children (the nested components).  In all likelihood you would add elements to the VGroup in AS3 so you'd probably want to give it an ID.

Your other option is to use a spark List and then set your visual component as the itemRenderer.  For each data element in the data provider for the list (some sort of collection class, ArrayCollection, XMLCollection etc.) it will set an element of the array as the "data" property on your visual component.  You would then use bindings to the data property in your visual component to make sure if the renderer is re-used/recycled the elements within it update automatically.  Here's an example of that:

```
    <s:List dataProvider="{new ArrayCollection([{name:'Shaun', birthday:'04-28-1983', imageSource:'someImage.png'}])}"
            itemRenderer="views.YourCustomComponent"
            width="100%"/>
```

In your case the dataProvider for the list could be assigned in the result handler code you have above, it appears result is an array so you can just wrap it in an ArrayCollection like myList.dataProvider = new ArrayCollection(result);

Here's a potential view definition for a single entry in the list (the itemRenderer class used above)

[views.YourCustomComponent]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:VGroup xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
          xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark"
          implements="mx.core.IDataRenderer">
    <fx:Script>
        <![CDATA[
            private var _data:Object;

            [Bindable(eventName="dataChanged")]
            public function get data():Object
            {
                return _data;   
            }
            public function set data(value:Object):void
            {
                if(_data == value)
                    return;
                _data = value;
                dispatchEvent(new Event("dataChanged"));
            }
        ]]>
    </fx:Script>
    <fx:Declarations>
        <!-- Place non-visual elements (e.g., services, value objects) here -->
    </fx:Declarations>
    <s:Label text="{data.name}"/>
    <s:Label text="{data.birthday}"/>
    <s:Image source="{data.imageSource}"/>
</s:VGroup>
```

There are certainly caveats and alternatives to these answers but this will hopefully get you going in the right direction, if you're doing this for mobile development be sure to check out the recommendations with regard to creating renderers for mobile, the idea here is to reduce the processing needed for creating and re-using renderers on mobile as much as possible to lighten the load on the CPU and memory.

One other thing to note it appears your mixing defining the view in AS3 and MXML, while this is technically okay I find it to be a bit confusing myself.  I would normally define the entire layout in MXML, or if need be entirely in AS3.  If defined in MXML and a component needs to be conditionally hidden by code I would just toggle the visible/includeInLayout properties.  I suppose this is just a preference but it seems it could get hairy determining what is causing particular layouts to occur when you have to look between the two to piece it together.

References to the AS3 reference for classes used:
http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/beta/reference/actionscript/3/spark/components/VGroup.html

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/beta/reference/actionscript/3/spark/components/Scroller.html

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/beta/reference/actionscript/3/spark/components/List.html

Details on custom item renderers http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/using/WS03d33b8076db57b9-23c04461124bbeca597-8000.html <-- references Jeffry Houser a regular on SO with the name www.flextras.com